# Can dapr self-hosted apps invoke a remote dapr service hosted on kubernetes?

Tags: azure-aks, dapr

My distributed dapr.io application is growing very quickly and contains several dapr app-ids; and running all applications locally for development purposes is becoming difficult.

Is it possible for a local self-hosted app in development to invoke a production app running on an AKS cluster?

Comment: Did you find a way to  do this without obscure vs code plugins?

Comment: Any updates on this question? We want to use Dapr but found it hard to have a hybrid local dev env.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to mix local development with existing services on AKS check out Bridge to Kubernetes

- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/bridge-to-kubernetes-ga/
- https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Visual-Studio-Toolbox/Bridge-to-Kubernetes

> this information is intended preliminary, I will try to bring up a Dapr sample scenario